# HSPICE command naming weirdness

Tags: simulation, spice, eda, hspice, synopsys

I have a simple digital invert circuit using ASAP7 nmos and pmos transistors. When I use Synopsys HSPICE to simulate the below script, it throws an error `Definition of model/subckt "nmos_rvt" is not found for the element "xinv1^xm1". Please specify a defined model/subckt name.`

However, when I change `xm0` to `mm0` (and xm1 to mm1) everything works! What is wrong with using `xm0` as the instance name? Where is this documented?

The script:

````
** Generated for: hspiceD
** Generated on: Feb  2 16:49:44 2021
** Design library name: demo
** Design cell name: invtest
** Design view name: schematic
.GLOBAL vdd!


.TEMP 25.0
.OPTION
+    ARTIST=2
+    INGOLD=2
+    PARHIER=LOCAL
+    PSF=2
.INCLUDE "7nm_TT.pm"

** Library name: asap7ssc7p5t
** Cell name: INVx1_ASAP7_75t_R
** View name: schematic
.subckt INVx1_ASAP7_75t_R a y vdd vss
xm1 y a vss vss nmos_rvt w=81e-9 l=20e-9 nfin=3
xm0 y a vdd vdd pmos_rvt w=81e-9 l=20e-9 nfin=3
.ends INVx1_ASAP7_75t_R
** End of subcircuit definition.

** Library name: demo
** Cell name: invtest
** View name: schematic
xinv1 in1 out1 vdd! 0 INVx1_ASAP7_75t_R
v0 vdd! 0 DC=700e-3
c0 out1 0 2e-15
VIN in1 0 0 pulse 0 0.7 0 50p 50p 2n 4n 
.tran 10p 10n
.END

```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard SPICE syntax and I suspect it is documented in many places. Instance names for MOSFETs must begin with `M` and instance names of subcircuits must begin with `X`. Voltage sources start with `V`, resistors start with `R`, and so on. The first letter tells SPICE how to parse the rest of the line.

It gets tricky when a MOSFET is actually described using a subcircuit rather than directly with a MOSFET model, but if it's a subcircuit then it needs to start with an `X`.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually from Virtuoso/ADE-L using the ASAP7 tech lib. Wonder why it decided to name it xm0 instead of mm0.

Answer (score 0):

make a new file with cover up the target models as below
it will solve the problems

```spice
.SUBCKT nmos_lvt  D G S BDY   W=27n L=7n NFIN=1
.INCLUDE "/home/vlsi/libfortech/asap7_pdk_r1p7/models/hspice/7nm_TT_160803.model"
M1    D G S BDY     nmos_lvt W=W L=L NFIN=NFIN

.ENDS nmos_lvt

.SUBCKT pmos_lvt  D G S BDY   W=27n L=7n NFIN=1
.INCLUDE "/home/vlsi/libfortech/asap7_pdk_r1p7/models/hspice/7nm_TT_160803.model"
M1    D G S BDY     pmos_lvt W=W L=L NFIN=NFIN

.ENDS pmos_lvt
```